# Downloading a specific branch of App from googlesource

Tags: git

After searching a lot I ask this.

I want to download the app source code from this url: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Gallery2/+/ics-mr1

git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Gallery2/+/ics-mr1 does not work.

git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Gallery2/ works just fine.

What should I do to download the specific branch?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Git clone download all the project, with `--branch` option:

> --branch , -b 
>              Instead of pointing the newly created HEAD to the branch pointed to by the cloned repository’s HEAD, point to 
>              branch instead. In a non-bare repository, this is the branch that will be checked out.

```
git clone --branch ics-mr1 https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Gallery2
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You clone the project and then you checkout the branch like:

```
git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Gallery2
cd Gallery2/
git checkout ics-mr1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also download just one branch:

```
git init Gallery2_ics-mr1
cd Gallery2_ics-mr1
git remote add origin https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Gallery2
git fetch -n origin ics-mr1:refs/remotes/origin/ics-mr1
git checkout origin/ics-mr1 -b ics-mr1
```

Note that further `git pull` or `git fetch` (without parameters) will fetch everything else from the repository.